# How do I access rounding modes defined in IEEE 754 in python?

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal, ieee-754, floating-point-precision

I have the need to compute exactly in single precision floating points in Python.

The options I've tried are `decimal.Decimal` and `numpy.float32`. However `Decimal` is not based on IEEE 754, and `float32` cannot allow the use of rounding modes. It is surprising rounding modes are standard features of IEEE 754 but there exists no built-in implementation of it in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [gmpy2](https://code.google.com/p/gmpy/) library will do what you want.

```
>>> import gmpy2                                                                                                                  
>>> gmpy2.set_context(gmpy2.ieee(32))
>>> ctx=gmpy2.get_context()
>>> ctx
context(precision=24, real_prec=Default, imag_prec=Default,
        round=RoundToNearest, real_round=Default, imag_round=Default,
        emax=128, emin=-148,
        subnormalize=True,
        trap_underflow=False, underflow=False,
        trap_overflow=False, overflow=False,
        trap_inexact=False, inexact=False,
        trap_invalid=False, invalid=False,
        trap_erange=False, erange=False,
        trap_divzero=False, divzero=False,
        trap_expbound=False,
        allow_complex=False)
>>> gmpy2.const_pi().digits(2)
('110010010000111111011011', 2, 24)
>>> ctx.round=gmpy2.RoundDown
>>> gmpy2.const_pi().digits(2)
('110010010000111111011010', 2, 24)
>>> ctx.round=gmpy2.RoundUp
>>> gmpy2.const_pi().digits(2)
('110010010000111111011011', 2, 24)
>>>
```

gmpy2 provides access to the GMP, MPFR, and MPC arbitrary-precision libraries. MPFR support correctly rounded arithmetic for user-definable precision and exponent limits.

Disclaimer: I maintain gmpy2.

Comment: Thank you! Does gmpy2 support exact computation for arithmetic operations, like `fractions.Fraction`?

Comment: Yes, gmpy2 also has a rational type called mpq.