# Tie breaking of round with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, rounding

Standard numpy round tie breaking is following IEEE 754 convention, to round half towards the nearest even number. Is there a way to specify different rounding behavior, e.g. round towards zero or towards -inf? I'm not talking about ceil or floor, I just need different tie breaking.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how can those tie-breaking rules become relevant in practice? After all, the difference is in the same order of magnitude as the quantization error.

Comment: I'm rebuilding some complex calculations from matlab in python. The tie breaking there is different, so it ruins some test cases, when I compare the results.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

NumPy doesn't give any control over the internal rounding mode. Here's two alternatives:

1. Use `gmpy2`, as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15104444/1204143). This gives you full control over the rounding mode, but using `gmpy2` for simple float math is likely to be slower than NumPy.
2. Use `fesetround` via `ctypes` to manually set the rounding mode. This is system-specific because the constants may vary by platform; check `fenv.h` for the constant values on your platform. On my machine (Mac OS X):

   ```
   import numpy as np
   import ctypes
   FE_TONEAREST = 0x0000
   FE_DOWNWARD = 0x0400
   FE_UPWARD = 0x0800
   FE_TOWARDZERO = 0x0c00
   libc = ctypes.CDLL('libc.dylib')

   v = 1. / (1<<23)
   print repr(np.float32(1+v) - np.float32(v/2)) # prints 1.0
   libc.fesetround(FE_UPWARD)
   print repr(np.float32(1+v) - np.float32(v/2)) # prints 1.0000002
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! For completeness: Using linux, I found fesetround not in libc, but in libm, so the load line was `libm = ctypes.CDLL('libm.so.6')`. The constants are the same.

Answer (score 0):

## With the open-source software SWIG

To complete nneonneo answer, if you don't want to download a big package like gmpy2 neither use a system-specific code with ctypes, you can use a binding from C with SWIG (assuming that you already have it on your computer).

Here is what you need to do (in four steps):

1) Write first a file named rounding.i :

```
%module rounding
%{
/* Put header files here or function declarations like below */

 void rnd_arr();
 void rnd_zero();
 void rnd_plinf();
 void rnd_moinf();
 void rnd_switch();
%}

extern  void rnd_arr();
extern  void rnd_zero();
extern  void rnd_plinf();
extern  void rnd_moinf();
extern  void rnd_switch();
```

2) Then, a file rnd_C.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fenv.h>


void rnd_arr()
{
  fesetround(FE_TONEAREST);
}


void rnd_zero()
{
  fesetround(FE_TOWARDZERO);
}

void rnd_plinf()
{
  fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
}

void rnd_moinf()
{
  fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
}

void rnd_switch()
{
  int r=fegetround();

  if (r==FE_UPWARD)
    r=FE_DOWNWARD;
  else 
    if (r==FE_DOWNWARD)
      r=FE_UPWARD;
    else fprintf(stderr,"ERROR ROUDING MODE \n");
  fesetround(r);
}
```

3) In your terminal (if you use another version than python2.7, replace python2.7 at the second line ):

```
swig -c++ -python -o rounding_wrap.cpp rounding.i
g++ -fPIC -c rounding_wrap.cpp rnd_C.cpp -I/usr/include/python2.7
g++ -shared rounding_wrap.o rnd_C.o -o _rounding.so
```

4) import the library _rounding.so that you just created by taping at the beginning of your python file :

```
from your_path_to_rounding.so import rounding
```

Comment: That `from` line is not right: shouldn’t it just be `import rounding`?

Comment: It worked for me with "from your_path_to_rounding.so import rounding " and I have no idea how to do with yours, sorry..

Comment: Wait—you must mean `from directory import rounding`.  I thought you were including the file name.