# Setting tensorflow rounding mode

Tags: python, tensorflow, rounding

I am working with small numbers in `tensorflow`, which sometimes results in **numerical instability**.

I would like to increase the precision of my results, or at the very least **determine bounds on my result**.

The following code shows a specific example of numerical errors (it outputs `nan` instead of `0.0`, because `float64` is not precise enough to handle `1+eps/2`):

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# setup
eps=np.finfo(np.float64).eps
v=eps/2
x_init=np.array([v,1.0,-1.0],dtype=np.float64)

x=tf.get_variable("x", initializer=tf.constant(x_init))
square=tf.reduce_sum(x)
root=tf.sqrt(square-v)

# run
with tf.Session() as session:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    session.run(init)

    ret=session.run(root)
    print(ret)
```

I am assuming there is no way to increase the precision of values in tensorflow. But maybe it is possible to set the rounding mode, as in C++ using `std::fesetround(FE_UPWARD)`? Then, I could force tensorflow to always round up, which would make sure that I am taking the square root of a non-negative number.

---

**What I tried:** I tried to follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000574/tie-breaking-of-round-with-numpy) that outlines how to set the rounding mode for python/numpy. However, this does not seem to work, because the following code still prints `nan`:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

import ctypes
FE_TONEAREST = 0x0000 # these constants may be system-specific
FE_DOWNWARD = 0x0400
FE_UPWARD = 0x0800
FE_TOWARDZERO = 0x0c00
libc = ctypes.CDLL('libm.so.6') # may need 'libc.dylib' on some systems

libc.fesetround(FE_UPWARD)

# setup
eps=np.finfo(np.float64).eps
v=eps/2
x_init=np.array([v,1.0,-1.0],dtype=np.float64)

x=tf.get_variable("x", initializer=tf.constant(x_init))
square=tf.reduce_sum(x)
root=tf.sqrt(square-v)

# run
with tf.Session() as session:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    session.run(init)
    ret=session.run(root)
    print(ret)
```

Comment: You have a bug in your provided code; you're always calculating 0 in your setup: `square=tf.reduce_sum(x) # equals v` followed by `root=tf.sqrt(square-v)`

Comment: Also, can you give any good reason why `eps=np.finfo(np.float32).eps` is unacceptably large?

Comment: @Multihunter This is just a minimal example that illustrates the problem (it should calculate `0`, but it returns `nan`). In real life, these errors can e.g. occur when calculating the sample variance or sample correlation of an array. `eps` is not too large in itself, but it can lead to wrong results due to cancellation (as `nan` in my example).

Comment: That's what I'm saying. I ran the code, and it always gives 0. My feeling is that tf.reduce_sum() is somehow avoiding falling out of precision. If you replace `tf.reduce_sum(x)` with `x[0]+x[1]+x[2]`, then you get `nan`. I'm using tensorflow v1.3.0. How about you?

Comment: @Multihunter Hmm, interesting. I am using tensorflow version `1.4.1` on `Python 3.5.2`. Seems like the behavior can change from version to version. All the more reason to find a general solution...

Comment: I just tested on tensorflow version 1.5.0 (latest, just came out a few days ago), and your code produces `nan`. So, something changed between v1.3 and v1.4 in reduce_sum that changes it's ability to handle intermediary results falling outside precision (and it's still there). If operations like reduce_sum were able to work like tf.reduce_sum does in v1.3.0, would that satisfy your requirements (if not your question)? (I'm assuming that you'll be doing vectorised operations like that)

Comment: @Multihunter I was hoping for a general solution, not one that relies on a specific implementation of `reduce_sum`. But it would probably solve my specific problem, so I would absolutely be grateful for a solution that achieves this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
ret=session.run(root)
```

with

```
ret = tf.where(tf.is_nan(root), tf.zeros_like(root), root).eval()
```

Refer [tf.where](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where)

Comment: The is a possible work-around, thanks! But I am guessing this makes the function non-differentiable? Also, this only works in this specific case of the square root. It would be nice to have a more generic solution.